# Reading iOS device generation and model number over USB using Python on Windows

Tags: python, ios, usb, communication, detection

Hello I have a GUI and I would like to detect iPod touches and iPhone's generations and model numbers over a usb connection on a desktop computer. I have seen libgpod but I use an windows machine and have little idea on how to install it (if its even compatible with windows)

My hope is that I can connect to the device, find and print the generation (it would be something like iPod 1,1 - iPod touch 1G) and then specify a file to download related to the device.

Comment: I think that you can take this in two different directions, using WMI to get the device and manufacturer values or to use pyusb/pywin32usb module to get information on the connected devices. I'm looking into this, I'll reply back when I can. my wmic tests aren't returning device and manufacturer values and I don't have an iPod to test with but I have things I can test.

Answer (score 1):

Well I wanted to give you a better answer with a code example, but this should get you started.

[pywinusb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinusb/) is your best bet, as it reads more information more reliably about the plugged in devices. There are a few good examples for outputting connected devices and the like out there, [here](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb) are some pretty good examples. You'll want to find the vendor_id or look for product_id 's for your usage, below is some example code.

```
from pywinusb import hid

# filter connected devices by vendor and product
filter = hid.HidDeviceFilter(vendor_id = 0x0777, product_id = 0x0077)

# filter connected devices by vendor
# filter = hid.HidDeviceFilter(vendor_id = 0x0777)

# filter connected devices by product
# filter = hid.HidDeviceFilter(product_id = 0x0077)

devices = filter.get_devices()

for device in devices:
    print device
```

You can find more [examples here](https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb/wiki/Introduction).

Possibly try using win32com to list the Win32_USBHub devices from WMI??

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):
    print "DeviceID - " + usb.DeviceID
    print "Name - " + usb.Name
    print "Description - " + usb.Description
    print "Caption - " + usb.Caption
    print "SystemName - " + usb.SystemName
    print "PNPDeviceID - " + usb.PNPDeviceID
    print "\n\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a shot and report back once I get time to implement it into my app

Comment: Update: I have used pywinusb and an iPod isn't a Human Interface Device... But it did pick up my laptops touchscreen so it is working.

Comment: I think I have to use this iTunesMobileDevice.dll somehow. (I may change language to VB or something along those lines...)

Comment: I've added in the WMI method, It's getting closer but not exactly going to give you what you need. I'm still looking, I think this might be useful for an idea I have and I'd like to help.

Comment: Hi I got a good result but not what I was expecting. Text is below (I have No idea how to do the code highlight)
DeviceID - USB\VID_05AC&PID_1291\272C8ECC653AF2B1BD24A417C8BB39C3886446C3
Name - Apple Mobile Device USB Driver
Description - Apple Mobile Device USB Driver
Caption - Apple Mobile Device USB Driver
SystemName - JAMES-LAPTOP
PNPDeviceID - USB\VID_05AC&PID_1291\272C8ECC653AF2B1BD24A417C8BB39C3886446C3